# multiple tab bar controller?

Tags: iphone

i have tab bar controller in which i have 4 tabs.suppose if i press 4th tab,i want to show another tab bar controller above that .any tutorial pls?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by adding a UITabBar inside of a standard view controller, and then using that view controller as one of the members of a UITabBarController's viewControllers array. But PLEASE DON'T. This is horrible UI.

Comment: I've seen worse in the AppStore, so if you don't get a cranky reviewer, you shouldn't have a problem. It will, however, confuse the user. Use a UINavigationController instead.