# Regarding tabBar controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi friends ,I have question ,Is this possible to use two different tabbar class in the same app.
It mean I have Two tabbar controller in my app.
Like 1st is newtabcontroller.h & newtabcontroller.m
2nd is oldtabcontroller.h & oldtabcontroller.m
is possible to use two different tabbarcontroller in app.
thanks

Comment: This seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907483/multiple-tab-bar-controller and others.

Answer (score 0):

why not?
But it should not be a tabbarcontroller inside another tabbarcontroller.

Have a `TabbarManager` class. Then on some condition, load
   - `FirstTabbarController` or 
   - `SecondTabbarController`

All components and the UITabbarControllers themselves should be instantiated in the TabbarManager class. 
Its `init` may have code like this, make similar for two tabbarcontrollers.

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// initialize the view controllers and navigation controllers for the tab bar

self.friendsVC = [[FriendsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *friendsNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: friendsVC];
friendsNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:friendsNVC];  
[friendsNVC release];

self.paymentsVC = [[PaymentsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaymentsView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *paymentsNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: paymentsVC];
paymentsNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:paymentsNVC];
[paymentsNVC release];  

tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; 
tabBarController.delegate = self;

self.view = tabBarController.view;
```